# El Capitan, Eclipse does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I had latest version of eclipse and JAVA on new OS X. Eclipse does not respond nor works. Any inputs to fix will be of great help.

Comment: What java did you install ? and what version of eclipse. and what exactly happens

Comment: Actually, just an update has come up on OS X El Capitan, I have installed it seems to working fine except I had issues with the workspace which I think I can fix them. Thanks for the response again.

Comment: To your initial question. I have the following, Eclipse : Version: Mars Release (4.5.0), JAVA : Version 8 update 51 (build 1.8.0_51-b16)

Comment: This is a known problem with beta 3, supposed to be fixed in beta 4.

Comment: Please include the exact build version so we can best help you - the same goes for eclipse (latest is a relative term that causes problems as a question ages)

Answer (score 2):

Probably because Eclipse needs to be updated for El Capitan, which will be released for "common use" this fall...

Comment: Actually the Eclipse bug report for this has been closed as 'not Eclipse'. The problem should be fixed in El Capitan beta 4.

Comment: There is a 7 page forum entry on this: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8776?tstart=0 — and I don't think it is an eclipse problem.